# Errors when using quicksort to sort a double

Tags: c#, arrays, string, quicksort

I have a string array that I convert to double, I pass it into the following quicksort algorithm and get multiple errors saying I cannot onvert double to int despite having a double array. Left and right are 0 and arr.Length - 1 respectively.

```
public static double[] quick_Sort(double[] arr, double left, double right)
    {

            double i, j;
            double pivot, temp;
            i = left;
            j = right;
            pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
            do
            {
                while ((arr[i] < pivot) && (i < right)) i++;
                while ((pivot < arr[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            } while (i <= j);
            if (left < j) quick_Sort(arr, left, j);
            if (i < right) quick_Sort(arr, i, right);

        return arr;

     }
```

Comment: Of the segment I've posted. 8, 11, 12 15, 16, 16, 17.

Comment: This code does not compile.

Comment: Because this is a segment of a much larger program.

Comment: No, because the variables are typed "double" when they should be int. This leaves the question what else is changed and might hide the real bug. One answerer already wasted his time with this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `double`s for your array indexes -- which are supposed to be `int`s, e.g.

```
arr[i]
```

You need to use `int` values for your indexes, e.g.:

```
int i;
i = Convert.ToInt32(left);
```

Or just use `int` instead of `double` for your all your variables (depending on how your program works).  I'm not sure what's best without more information.